# Kivy getting values from Popup Window and use it at a Screen

Tags: popup, kivy, screen, kivy-language

Hi i am new to kivy and just started programming. So what i want to do is,once a user key in a valid date/time in the popup window, popup will close and will goes to a screen and create buttons. May i know how to pass the values get from getDay() which is dayoutput,timeoutput from popupwindow and transfer use it in another other class? and be able to use in the VariesTimeScreen?

Thank your for taking your time to help :)

```
class SetDateTime(Popup):

    def getDay(self):

     set_day = (self.ids.dayofmonth).text
     set_month = (self.ids.month).text
     set_year = (self.ids.year).text

     set_hour = (self.ids.houroftime).text
     set_minutes = (self.ids.minuteoftime).text

     wrongtime = self.ids.wronginput_time

#Calculate Date and Time only when user input a valid number
     if set_day.isdigit() and set_month.isdigit() and 
          set_year.isdigit()andset_hour.isdigit() 
          and set_minutes.isdigit():           
         try:
            set_date = datetime.date(int(set_year), 
            int(set_month),int(set_day))
            set_time = datetime.time(int(set_hour), int(set_minutes))

            if not (set_date >= counttime.todaydate()):
              wrongtime.text = "[color=#FF0000]Date is out of 
              range[/color]"
              if not (set_time >= counttime.todaytime()):
                   wrongtime.text = "[color=#FF0000]Time is out of 
                   range[/color]"

             dayoutput = counttime.calculatedate(set_date)
             timeoutput = set_hour + set_minutes
             self.dismiss()
             return dayoutput,timeoutput
          except ValueError:
            wrongtime.text = "[color=#FF0000]Please enter a valid 
                             datetime.[/color]"

      else:
         wrongtime.text = "[color=#FF0000]Please enter a valid 
         date[/color]"


class VariesTimeScreen(Screen):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(VariesTimeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    a = '_icons_/mcdonald.png'
    b = '_icons_/kfc.png'
    c = '_icons_/subway.png'

    Outlet_Store = [a,b,c]
    layout = GridLayout(rows=1, spacing=100, size_hint_y=None, 
                     pos_hint ={"top":.6,"x":0.2})
    layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

            #Before the for loop there will be an if statement which is 
            the Day and Time i get from getDay() values. This part i'm 
            unsure how to retrieve the values from the SetDateTime Class

            for image in Outlet_Store: 
               food_image = ImageButton(size_hint=(None, None),size= 
                            (100,100),source=image)

               layout.add_widget(food_image)
            self.add_widget(layout)
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. If you post a complete app that I can cut, paste, and run to see what you are trying to do, it makes it much easier for us to help you. Doesn't need to be your complete app (actually, better if it is not), but just enough to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help, i post my code at this link. Cause idk why it seems like i cant edit it in stackoverflow it keep giving me error sorry. https://shrib.com/#.2D6QRrxMOSy5rV9LQ7B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your design is that the `VariesTimeScreen` is created very early in the `App` run, like when the `GUI` is created. So, the day and time from the `SetDateTime` `Popup` is not yet available. One way to handle this is to add an `on_enter()` method to the `VariesTimeScreen` to make any adjustments to the `Screen` at that time. To do that, I added `Properties` to the `VariesTimeScreen`:

```
class VariesTimeScreen(Screen):
    day = StringProperty('None')
    time = NumericProperty(0)
```

And add the `on_enter()` method to the `VariesTimeScreen` class:

```
def on_enter(self, *args):
    print('day:', self.day, ', time:', self.time)
    # make changes to the Screen
```

And then change the `SetDateTime` class slightly:

```
class SetDateTime(Popup):

    def getDay(self):
        set_day = (self.ids.dayofmonth).text
        set_month = (self.ids.month).text
        set_year = (self.ids.year).text

        set_hour = (self.ids.houroftime).text
        set_minutes = (self.ids.minuteoftime).text

        wrongtime = self.ids.wronginput_time

        # Calculate Date and Time only when user input a valid number
        if set_day.isdigit() and set_month.isdigit() and set_year.isdigit() and set_hour.isdigit() and set_minutes.isdigit():
            try:
                set_date = datetime.date(int(set_year),
                                         int(set_month), int(set_day))
                set_time = datetime.time(int(set_hour), int(set_minutes))

                if not (set_date >= counttime.todaydate()):
                    wrongtime.text = "[color=#FF0000]Date is out of range[ / color]"
                    if not (set_time >= counttime.todaytime()):
                        wrongtime.text = "[color=#FF0000]Time is out of range[ / color]"

                dayoutput = counttime.calculatedate(set_date)
                timeoutput = set_hour + set_minutes

                # get the VariesTimeScreen
                varies_time = App.get_running_app().root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen('variestime_screen')

                # set the day and time for the VariesTimeScreen
                varies_time.day = dayoutput
                varies_time.time = timeoutput

                # switch to the VariesTimeScreen
                App.get_running_app().change_screen('variestime_screen')

                # dismiss Popup
                self.dismiss()
            except ValueError:
                wrongtime.text = "[color=#FF0000]Please enter a valid datetime.[ / color]"

        else:
            wrongtime.text = "[color=#FF0000]Please enter a valid date[ / color]"
```

The only changes are to set the `day` and `time` in the `VariesTimeScreen`, and to actually switch to the `VariesTimeScreen`. The switch to the `VariesTimeScreen` doesn't have to happen there, once the `day` and `time` are set, the `on_enter()` method will get called whenever it becomes the current `Screen`.

Comment: Thank You so much Sir you've helped me a lot. Now I am able to make the popup closes when user input key in a valid input. Also, by using the on_enter function, it create the button according to the date/time.